# Get the nearest less than value

Tags: mysql

I need to get the nearest less than value from the table..
that is if my table is as follows

```
+----+----------+---------------------+
| id | display  | email               |
+----+----------+---------------------+
|  1 | 7        | myuser@example.com  |
+----+----------+---------------------+
|  2 | 1        | myuser@example.com  |
+----+----------+---------------------+
|  3 | 10        | myuser@example.com |
+----+----------+---------------------+
|  4 | 8        | myuser@example.com  |
+----+----------+---------------------+
```

I need to get the display which is less than 8.here there is 7 and 1.But i need only 7 which is the first less than value of 8.Please help me to find a logic to get this..

Comment: use sorting. then next value will be the near value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `MAX()` function to get the highest value that meets the criteria.

```
SELECT MAX(display)
FROM yourTable
WHERE display < 8
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is using `order by / limit`

```
select *
from your_table
where display < 8
order by display desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sorting.

```
SELECT * FROM TB WHERE display < 8 ORDER BY display DESC LIMIT 1
```